# Passing URL into method

Tags: iphone, xcode, methods

Hi i have a question here,

i'm able to get the UrL string store in "imageName" variable successfully in showImage method.

I need to do the same in this method "segmentedControlIndexChanged" but i cant get the variable "imageName".

Is there anyway i can declare the IBAction method to work similarly as the showImage method?

I Tried ->" `-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged:(NSString *)imageName{}` " but it cant work, i'm unable to get the variable "imageName".

```
- (void) showImage:(NSString *)imageName

{

      NSData *imageData; 


      //NSString * string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:imageName];

      imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageName]];

      //NSLog(@"%@",imageName);

      image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

      self.imageView.image = image;

      [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, image.size.width, image.size.height)]; 

      [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];

      if(image.size.height+20 >= 224)

      {

            [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(289, image.size.height + 20)];

      }

      else {

            [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(289, 224)];

      } 


} 


//////// 



-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged{ 




      switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {

            case 0:

                  image = [UIImage imageNamed:image1name];

                  self.imageView.image = image;

                  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

                  [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];

                  if(image.size.height+20 >= 224)

                  {

                        [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(289, image.size.height + 20)];

                  }

                  else {

                        [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(289, 224)];

                  }

                  break; 


            case 1:

                  image = [UIImage imageNamed:image2name];

                  self.imageView.image = image;

                  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, image.size.width, image.size.height)];

                  [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];

                  [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(289, image.size.height+20)];

                  break;

            case 2:

                  image = [UIImage imageNamed:image3name];

                  self.imageView.image = image;

                  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, image.size.width, image.size.height+1)];

                  [scrollview setScrollEnabled:YES];

                  [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(289, image.size.height+20)];

                  break;

            default:

                  break; 


      }

}
```

**EDIT**

I have encountered Bad Access error, anyone knows what does it mean or can anyone show me some ways to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an IBAction can only have one of the following three signatures in iOS:

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

**EDIT**

You could extend UIButton to store the value you need, like:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;

@end

...

@implementation MyButton

@synthesize url;

@end

...

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    MyButton *button = (MyButton *)sender;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:button.url];
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use tags to differentiate between different senders, like

```
enum {
    ButtonOneTag = 128,
    ButtonTwoTag,
    ...
}

...

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch(button.tag) {
        case ButtonOneTag:
            NSLog(@"Button One Tapped");
            break;
        case ButtonTwoTag:
            NSLog(@"Button Two Tapped");
            break;
}
```

You can also just compare the sender to ivars for the buttons like so:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    //assuming buttonOne and buttonTwo are IBOutlets on this class
    if (sender == self.buttonOne) {
        NSLog(@"Button One Tapped");
    else if (sender == self.buttonTwo) {
        NSLog(@"Button Two Tapped");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: so if i have 18 buttons calling the same method, i need 18 cases?

Comment: Basically, yes, but you could extend UIButton to store the url if that simplifies things. I've added an example above.